# Writing django tests that use the main database

Tags: django, testing

My django project has several data migrations which take about 2 hours to be applied. Those data migrations constitute a series of transformations on a raw dataset (cleaning up, extracting new fields, etc.). The final state of the database consists of 15-20 tables.

I also have code that imports new data on a daily basis which is also pushed to the existing database tables in the same format.

I want to write tests that make sure that the contents of the database are correct at any given moment (after the initial data migrations have been applied, after a new import, etc.). The tests will check things like whether a particular column which is not expected to have null values indeed doesn't, if a derived field's value is correct, etc.

My issue is that, django attempts to create a test database by applying all migrations every time I run the tests. But since the data migrations take a long time to be applied, running tests like that becomes very impractical. I also don't want to use the keepdb option, as I want to run those tests after changes to the original database as well.

I'm not sure what the general best idiomatic django approach is for such cases.

Answer (score 2):

Make a backup of your current database and name it as 'test_database_name'.

Eg. DB_name = django. Then keep the backup database's name as test_django.

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_name > database_backup.sql
mysql -u username -p test_database_name < database_backup.sql
```

When you run the tests, use this command

```
python manage.py test --keepdb
```

Django will use the backup DB for testing and then you don't have to apply migrations again and again. But make sure the name of the test database is correct. The command --keepdb will keep the DB and won't allow Django to delete the database everytime you run tests.

Also, every time you run the tests, Django will flush all the data in the backup DB but it won't flush migrations. So every time you run the test you have to make a **SetUp class** to set all the users, permissions, groups etc.

Comment: Thank you! This will save sooooo much time! It should honestly be the default behavior for Django test :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can run the django test case to persistence  the test db.

```
python manage.py test -k
```

It will create test database onece, it keeps that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! Is there no way to prevent django from creating the test database to begin with? My tests never actually modify the database, so there's no risk in performing them on the main database.

Comment: if there will be no database , how you will display the data, it means that's a static website.

Comment: There is a database. I just don't want to create a separate test database just for testing but run the test using the main database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pytest` to acess / reuse database.

Just use `@pytest.mark.django_db` in your test case.

`pytest` is great for testing your django code. I definitely recommend it.

See [here](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html) for more information

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I couldn't quite gather this from the link, but am I right that using pytest doesn't require the creation of a test database?